# UIStackView in UITableViewCell going out of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I have used UIStackView in UITableViewCell to show additional cards for a primary card in following screen,
screen for primary and additional cards
[image]

Additional cards of a primary card can collapse/expand by touching bar with text "ADDITIONAL CARDS".

It was working fine if additional cards are less then screen size, in case of additional card more then screen size, tableview become scrollable, then on expanding/Collapsing additional cards, content of tableview goes out of screen.

content of uitableview goes out of screen

[image]

Comment: Why are you preferring `uistackview` here? Any specific reasons?

Comment: What is the issue, though? You have too many rows for your screen. . . And this doesn't seem like a good design. When the sections are expanded, you need to reload your table with a reconfiguration.

Comment: but stackview should expand downward...

Comment: When you are expanding to show your stack view, you need to tell the tableview that you are resizing that row; you can also make sure to reposition the tableview to show the top/middle/bottom of your row so you can control how scrolling happens.